# Lenovo Thinkpad AMD Radeon 680M randomly goes black for no obvious reason

Tags: drivers, graphics, lenovo, radeon, flicker

The Laptop is new, it's running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
Flickering and screen turning black while browsing, processing etc. More common during graphic related tasks, like raw converter.

Sounds like a driver issue. I don't find drivers for Linux for AMD Ryzen™ 7 PRO 7840U or AMD Radeon 680M on the AMD page.
Where do I find a generic AMD driver for Ubuntu 22.04 and how do I update it?

Problem turned worse with ClamTK installed, and turned better with deinstalling it. But still persisting.

While testing a simple 3D game, it turned hot quickly. Otherwise it runs silent and cool. So maybe heat related problem.

I have no Linux experience, so I need clear and basic advice.

as suggested:
lspci -knn | grep -iEA5 'vga|3d|display'

Result:

```
pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt [1002:1681] (rev d1)
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
04:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1640]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

uname -mrs # Demonstrate your kernel version

```
Linux 6.2.0-35-generic x86_64
```

Updated to:

```
Linux 6.5.7-060507-generic x86_64
```

Visual alerts are off.

glxinfo | grep OpenGL

```
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: REMBRANDT (rembrandt, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.49, 6.2.0-35-generic)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Edit: I noticed, that while being in the Application manager, flickering sends me back to Desktop view

Edit: Hardware scan of CPU and Display during Bios showed no problems.

Edit: Upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10. Works better, but the issues remain.

Edit:
$ sudo lshw -c video

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Rembrandt [Radeon 680M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: d1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=1920x1200 resolution=1920,1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
       resources: iomemory:80-7f iomemory:80-7f irq:42 memory:8b0000000-8bfffffff memory:8c0000000-8c01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:80800000-8087ffff
```

Edit dmesg -l warn returns:

```
[    0.133342] Speculative Return Stack Overflow: IBPB-extending microcode not applied!
[    0.133343] Speculative Return Stack Overflow: WARNING: See https://kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/srso.html for mitigation options.
[    0.314674] mtrr: your CPUs had inconsistent fixed MTRR settings
[    0.314674] mtrr: your CPUs had inconsistent variable MTRR settings
[    0.386583] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GP11: Overriding _PRW sleep state (S4) by S0 from power resources
[    0.388029] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GP12: Overriding _PRW sleep state (S4) by S0 from power resources
[    0.395049] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GP19.NHI0: Overriding _PRW sleep state (S3) by S0 from power resources
[    0.395752] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GP19.NHI1: Overriding _PRW sleep state (S3) by S0 from power resources
[    0.628877] pci 0000:00:00.2: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[    0.628881] pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT A: not connected
[    0.684092] device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
[    0.684210] platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
[    0.684212] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
[    0.684214] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
[    0.684215] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
[    0.684216] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
[    0.684217] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
[    0.684219] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
[    0.684220] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
[    0.684221] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
[    0.762604] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:80b4d96931bf0d02fd91a61e19d14f1da452e66db2408ca8604d411f92659f0a
[    0.762607] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:f52f83a3fa9cfbd6920f722824dbe4034534d25b8507246b3b957dac6e1bce7a
[    0.762609] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:c5d9d8a186e2c82d09afaa2a6f7f2e73870d3e64f72c4e08ef67796a840f0fbd
[    0.762611] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:1aec84b84b6c65a51220a9be7181965230210d62d6d33c48999c6b295a2b0a06
[    0.762613] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:c3a99a460da464a057c3586d83cef5f4ae08b7103979ed8932742df0ed530c66
[    0.762615] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:58fb941aef95a25943b3fb5f2510a0df3fe44c58c95e0ab80487297568ab9771
[    0.762617] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:5391c3a2fb112102a6aa1edc25ae77e19f5d6f09cd09eeb2509922bfcd5992ea
[    0.762619] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:d626157e1d6a718bc124ab8da27cbb65072ca03a7b6b257dbdcbbd60f65ef3d1
[    0.762621] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:d063ec28f67eba53f1642dbf7dff33c6a32add869f6013fe162e2c32f1cbe56d
[    0.762623] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:29c6eb52b43c3aa18b2cd8ed6ea8607cef3cfae1bafe1165755cf2e614844a44
[    0.762625] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:90fbe70e69d633408d3e170c6832dbb2d209e0272527dfb63d49d29572a6f44c
[    0.762626] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:106faceacfecfd4e303b74f480a08098e2d0802b936f8ec774ce21f31686689c
[    0.762628] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:174e3a0b5b43c6a607bbd3404f05341e3dcf396267ce94f8b50e2e23a9da920c
[    0.762630] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:2b99cf26422e92fe365fbf4bc30d27086c9ee14b7a6fff44fb2f6b9001699939
[    0.762632] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:2e70916786a6f773511fa7181fab0f1d70b557c6322ea923b2a8d3b92b51af7d
[    0.762634] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:3fce9b9fdf3ef09d5452b0f95ee481c2b7f06d743a737971558e70136ace3e73
[    0.762636] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:47cc086127e2069a86e03a6bef2cd410f8c55a6d6bdb362168c31b2ce32a5adf
[    0.762638] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:71f2906fd222497e54a34662ab2497fcc81020770ff51368e9e3d9bfcbfd6375
[    0.762639] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:82db3bceb4f60843ce9d97c3d187cd9b5941cd3de8100e586f2bda5637575f67
[    0.762641] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:8ad64859f195b5f58dafaa940b6a6167acd67a886e8f469364177221c55945b9
[    0.762643] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:8d8ea289cfe70a1c07ab7365cb28ee51edd33cf2506de888fbadd60ebf80481c
[    0.762645] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:aeebae3151271273ed95aa2e671139ed31a98567303a332298f83709a9d55aa1
[    0.762647] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:c409bdac4775add8db92aa22b5b718fb8c94a1462c1fe9a416b95d8a3388c2fc
[    0.762649] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:c617c1a8b1ee2a811c28b5a81b4c83d7c98b5b0c27281d610207ebe692c2967f
[    0.762651] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:c90f336617b8e7f983975413c997f10b73eb267fd8a10cb9e3bdbfc667abdb8b
[    0.762652] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:64575bd912789a2e14ad56f6341f52af6bf80cf94400785975e9f04e2d64d745
[    0.762654] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:45c7c8ae750acfbb48fc37527d6412dd644daed8913ccd8a24c94d856967df8e
[    0.762835] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:47ff1b63b140b6fc04ed79131331e651da5b2e2f170f5daef4153dc2fbc532b1
[    0.762837] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:5391c3a2fb112102a6aa1edc25ae77e19f5d6f09cd09eeb2509922bfcd5992ea
[    0.762876] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:80b4d96931bf0d02fd91a61e19d14f1da452e66db2408ca8604d411f92659f0a
[    0.762909] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:992d359aa7a5f789d268b94c11b9485a6b1ce64362b0edb4441ccc187c39647b
[    0.762952] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:c452ab846073df5ace25cca64d6b7a09d906308a1a65eb5240e3c4ebcaa9cc0c
[    0.762978] blacklist: Duplicate blacklisted hash bin:e051b788ecbaeda53046c70e6af6058f95222c046157b8c4c1b9c2cfc65f46e5
[    1.114593] r8169 0000:01:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   10.735733] systemd[1]: memfd_create() called without MFD_EXEC or MFD_NOEXEC_SEAL set
[   13.584481] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[   23.919791] kauditd_printk_skb: 218 callbacks suppressed
[   31.861079] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   31.861083] WARNING: CPU: 14 PID: 244 at drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/../display/dc/dce/dmub_psr.c:224 dmub_psr_enable+0x102/0x110 [amdgpu]
[   31.861349] Modules linked in: ccm michael_mic rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer bnep btusb btrtl btbcm btintel btmtk bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc uvc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videodev videobuf2_common mc qrtr_mhi binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common joydev snd_soc_acp6x_mach snd_acp6x_pdm_dma snd_soc_dmic snd_ctl_led snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_sof_amd_rembrandt snd_sof_amd_renoir snd_sof_amd_acp snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_intel qrtr snd_sof edac_mce_amd snd_sof_utils ath11k_pci snd_hda_codec snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi ath11k snd_hda_core snd_soc_core snd_hwdep kvm_amd snd_compress qmi_helpers kvm ac97_bus snd_seq_midi snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_seq_midi_event snd_pci_ps snd_rpl_pci_acp6x mac80211 snd_rawmidi snd_acp_pci thinkpad_acpi irqbypass snd_pci_acp6x nvram snd_seq rapl think_lmi ledtrig_audio snd_pcm wmi_bmof firmware_attributes_class snd_seq_device platform_profile
[   31.861431]  cfg80211 snd_pci_acp5x snd_timer snd_rn_pci_acp3x libarc4 snd_acp_config snd_soc_acpi mhi snd k10temp i2c_piix4 ccp snd_pci_acp3x soundcore nxp_nci_i2c nxp_nci nci nfc amd_pmc acpi_tad input_leds hid_multitouch mac_hid serio_raw msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport efi_pstore dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 dm_crypt usbhid amdgpu amdxcp iommu_v2 drm_buddy gpu_sched i2c_algo_bit drm_suballoc_helper drm_ttm_helper ttm drm_display_helper crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul cec polyval_clmulni polyval_generic nvme rc_core ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel r8169 drm_kms_helper nvme_core hid_generic video crypto_simd xhci_pci ucsi_acpi cryptd psmouse drm typec_ucsi xhci_pci_renesas nvme_common realtek typec i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid wmi hid
[   31.861545] CPU: 14 PID: 244 Comm: kworker/14:1H Not tainted 6.5.7-060507-generic #202310102154
[   31.861549] Hardware name: LENOVO 21J6S05000/21J6S05000, BIOS R23ET70W (1.40 ) 08/08/2023
[   31.861552] Workqueue: events_highpri dm_irq_work_func [amdgpu]
[   31.861940] RIP: 0010:dmub_psr_enable+0x102/0x110 [amdgpu]
[   31.862326] Code: 48 8b 45 d8 65 48 2b 04 25 28 00 00 00 75 1f 48 83 c4 50 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d 31 c0 31 d2 31 c9 31 f6 31 ff e9 ee c9 e1 ee <0f> 0b eb d2 e8 d5 36 e0 ee 0f 1f 44 00 00 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90
[   31.862329] RSP: 0018:ffffa2abc07a3c90 EFLAGS: 00010246
[   31.862333] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00000000000003e9 RCX: 0000000000000000
[   31.862336] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[   31.862338] RBP: ffffa2abc07a3d00 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[   31.862340] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
[   31.862342] R13: ffff90a41621e040 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff90a416040000
[   31.862345] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff90aa62180000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   31.862348] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   31.862350] CR2: 00007efff401c000 CR3: 00000003b383a000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
[   31.862353] PKRU: 55555554
[   31.862355] Call Trace:
[   31.862358]  <TASK>
[   31.862363]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[   31.862371]  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
[   31.862378]  ? dmub_psr_enable+0x102/0x110 [amdgpu]
[   31.862692]  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
[   31.862698]  ? handle_bug+0x51/0xa0
[   31.862702]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
[   31.862705]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
[   31.862710]  ? dmub_psr_enable+0x102/0x110 [amdgpu]
[   31.862906]  ? __pfx_dmub_psr_enable+0x10/0x10 [amdgpu]
[   31.863100]  edp_set_psr_allow_active+0x1ba/0x330 [amdgpu]
[   31.863292]  ? drm_dp_dpcd_write+0x88/0x120 [drm_display_helper]
[   31.863304]  dp_handle_hpd_rx_irq+0x329/0x360 [amdgpu]
[   31.863493]  dc_link_handle_hpd_rx_irq+0x26/0x40 [amdgpu]
[   31.863675]  handle_hpd_rx_irq+0xe1/0x320 [amdgpu]
[   31.863865]  dm_irq_work_func+0x19/0x30 [amdgpu]
[   31.864051]  process_one_work+0x223/0x440
[   31.864056]  worker_thread+0x4d/0x3f0
[   31.864058]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   31.864062]  ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0xe/0x20
[   31.864065]  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
[   31.864067]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[   31.864071]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[   31.864073]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[   31.864077]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[   31.864079]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[   31.864084]  </TASK>
[   31.864086] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[   33.002012] mmap: matroskademux0: (5616): VmData 1939980288 exceed data ulimit 1839744607. Update limits or use boot option ignore_rlimit_data.
[   52.165693] warning: `ThreadPoolForeg' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211
[   80.444007] kauditd_printk_skb: 75 callbacks suppressed
```

Comment: Attach output of `lspci -knn | grep -iEA5 'vga|3d|display'` command

Comment: Bozo do exactly like " RA " above tells you to do. Press the CTL + ALT + T keys together so your Terminal will open. Then COPY and PASTE      lspci -knn | grep -iEA5 'vga|3d|display'   hit enter. Then copy and paste that output from the terminal into your question main body, via editing.

Comment: Kernel versions seems new enough with 6.2

Comment: I'm hesitant to change the Grub value, since I do not understand enough and the problem in that cases seems to be with intel hardware

Comment: Visual alerts are off.

Comment: The driver seems to be loaded. You could also attach `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

Comment: Well the driver is included in the kernel and seems to be "working". It might have bugs though. My advice is try installing other kernels (e.g. 5.15 or 6.5). Or other Ubuntu versions (e.g. 22.04.2, 23.10)

Comment: @RA Kernel 6.5 does not solve the problem. I was unable to install 5.15 or 5.19 I will try to change the Ubuntu version

Comment: @RA Update to 23.10 has seemingly improved stuff, it has reduced blackening of the screen, but still some flickering.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my Thinkpad T14 Gen 3 AMD with 680M. Does your dmesg shows a warning like this?

```
[  238.283573] WARNING: CPU: 11 PID: 230 at drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/../display/dc/dce/dmub_psr.c:224 dmub_psr_enable+0x101/0x110 [amdgpu]
[  238.283917] Modules linked in: rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq snd_seq_device ccm michael_mic cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep af_packet btusb btrtl btintel btbcm btmtk bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc crc16 qrtr_mhi uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc uvc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videodev videobuf2_common mc xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 nft_chain_nat nf_nat qrtr ath11k_pci ath11k nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 snd_soc_dmic snd_acp6x_pdm_dma snd_soc_acp6x_mach vfat snd_sof_amd_vangogh fat snd_sof_amd_rembrandt snd_sof_amd_renoir snd_sof_amd_acp qmi_helpers snd_sof_pci snd_ctl_led snd_sof_xtensa_dsp mac80211 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_sof snd_hda_codec_generic joydev snd_sof_utils mousedev snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_core snd_hda_intel snd_compress tpm_crb snd_intel_dspcfg ac97_bus intel_rapl_msr hid_multitouch snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_pci_ps cfg80211 edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec snd_rpl_pci_acp6x snd_acp_pci edac_core snd_acp_legacy_common intel_rapl_common snd_hda_core
[  238.284001]  crc32_pclmul polyval_clmulni snd_pci_acp6x thinkpad_acpi polyval_generic snd_hwdep r8169 gf128mul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pci_acp5x snd_pcm nvram sp5100_tco ledtrig_audio ucsi_acpi snd_rn_pci_acp3x platform_profile mhi watchdog snd_acp_config realtek think_lmi typec_ucsi mdio_devres snd_timer rfkill snd_soc_acpi psmouse rapl wmi_bmof tiny_power_button snd typec k10temp libphy i2c_piix4 snd_pci_acp3x libarc4 firmware_attributes_class thermal soundcore roles ac battery fan i2c_hid_acpi tpm_tis i2c_hid tpm_tis_core amd_pmc acpi_tad button evdev mac_hid serio_raw xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 ip6t_rpfilter ipt_rpfilter xt_pkttype xt_LOG nf_log_syslog xt_tcpudp nft_compat nf_tables sch_fq_codel nfnetlink msr uinput ctr loop tun tap macvlan bridge stp llc hid_nintendo hid_playstation led_class_multicolor ff_memless kvm_amd ccp kvm irqbypass acpi_call(O) fuse efi_pstore configfs efivarfs dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 dm_crypt cbc encrypted_keys trusted asn1_encoder tee tpm
[  238.284102]  rng_core hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid xhci_pci input_leds xhci_pci_renesas xhci_hcd led_class nvme atkbd sha512_ssse3 libps2 sha512_generic vivaldi_fmap nvme_core usbcore aesni_intel libaes crypto_simd t10_pi cryptd crc64_rocksoft crc64 i8042 usb_common crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common serio rtc_cmos dm_mod dax btrfs blake2b_generic libcrc32c crc32c_generic crc32c_intel xor raid6_pq amdgpu i2c_algo_bit drm_ttm_helper ttm agpgart video wmi drm_exec drm_suballoc_helper amdxcp drm_buddy gpu_sched drm_display_helper drm_kms_helper drm backlight firmware_class
[  238.284163] CPU: 11 PID: 230 Comm: kworker/11:1H Tainted: G           O       6.6.0 #1-NixOS
[  238.284166] Hardware name: LENOVO 21CFCTO1WW/21CFCTO1WW, BIOS R23ET70W (1.40 ) 08/08/2023
[  238.284169] Workqueue: events_highpri dm_irq_work_func [amdgpu]
[  238.284468] RIP: 0010:dmub_psr_enable+0x101/0x110 [amdgpu]
[  238.284755] Code: c0 75 c5 81 fb e8 03 00 00 74 1f 48 8b 44 24 48 65 48 2b 04 25 28 00 00 00 75 13 48 83 c4 50 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d e9 7f 8e 70 e5 <0f> 0b eb dd e8 76 0c 6f e5 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 90 90 90 90 90 90 90
[  238.284757] RSP: 0018:ffffc900006a7cf0 EFLAGS: 00010246
[  238.284760] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00000000000003e9 RCX: 000000000002c91c
[  238.284761] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000055555554 RDI: ffffc900006a7c48
[  238.284763] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  238.284764] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff888103094280
[  238.284765] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffc900006a7dce R15: 0000000000000000
[  238.284766] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88883e780000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  238.284768] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  238.284769] CR2: 00007f592e1e7000 CR3: 000000046f620000 CR4: 0000000000f50ee0
[  238.284771] PKRU: 55555554
[  238.284772] Call Trace:
[  238.284776]  <TASK>
[  238.284777]  ? dmub_psr_enable+0x101/0x110 [amdgpu]
[  238.285050]  ? __warn+0x81/0x130
[  238.285057]  ? dmub_psr_enable+0x101/0x110 [amdgpu]
[  238.285331]  ? report_bug+0x171/0x1a0
[  238.285336]  ? handle_bug+0x41/0x70
[  238.285340]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x17/0x70
[  238.285342]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1a/0x20
[  238.285347]  ? dmub_psr_enable+0x101/0x110 [amdgpu]
[  238.285522]  edp_set_psr_allow_active+0x1be/0x3b0 [amdgpu]
[  238.285743]  dp_handle_hpd_rx_irq+0x3f3/0x460 [amdgpu]
[  238.285898]  handle_hpd_rx_irq+0xcb/0x2b0 [amdgpu]
[  238.286062]  process_one_work+0x174/0x340
[  238.286067]  worker_thread+0x27b/0x3a0
[  238.286070]  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
[  238.286072]  kthread+0xe8/0x120
[  238.286075]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[  238.286077]  ret_from_fork+0x34/0x50
[  238.286081]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[  238.286082]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[  238.286088]  </TASK>
[  238.286089] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```

Use `dmesg -l warn` to check if you do. Also, while I don't have a permanent solution to this, I am able to turn the screen back on by switching TTY. To try this, use Ctrl+Alt+F2 and then Ctrl+Alt+F1 to switch back. I'm not sure which TTY your screen is on (mine was on 1 hence F1). Try F7 if F1 does not work for you and report back here.

Comment: Done, I edited my post. Looks totally different, but I cannot make sense of it. But my problem seems to differ. The screen turned black only for half a second. Since I updated the kernel to 6.5 the blackening is mostly gone, but the flickering remains.